# Mobile bookmarks on desktop chrome bookmark bar

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, mobile-url

I would like to have my `Mobile bookmarks` appear on the bookmark bar of my desktop chrome browser. I would like `Mobile bookmarks` to appear besides the `Other bookmarks` which appears at the right-end side of the bookmakr bar.

Comment: Questions about web browser functionality belong on [su].

Comment: It used to do that.  Seems something is broken now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that it would be nice. But apparently there is no way to do it at this time. I guess that Google Chrome developers just didn't think of it. You could try providing feedback directly to them: https://support.google.com/chrome/#topic=3227046

Comment: But it used to work -- especially back in 2015.  Answer below works as a workaround I guess.

Answer (score 6):

There is a work around:

1. Verify the url of your mobile bookmark from your bookmarks. Go to chrome menu>>Bookmarks>>click on bookmark manager.
2. Highlight your mobile bookmark and copy the url... something like this: chrome://bookmarks/#3
3. Then right click your bookmark bar, select add a page. Name the page and past the url from step 2 above... same and voila!

Comment: This seems to have stopped giving you access to the URL.  It seems that `chrome://bookmarks/#3` is the most common, but just play around with the number until it highlights `Mobile bookmarks`

Comment: It was `chrome://bookmarks/?id=3#3` in my case, but the list was quite old.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it.

1) I created a new folder on my Bookmark bar and named it whatever.

2) I went to "Bookmarks" on the Google Chrome Menu bar in the top left corner.

3) I clicked on "Bookmark Manager" and then clicked on "Mobile Bookmarks"

4) I selected all of the mobile bookmarks by pressing Control/Command + A. Then, I clicked on the three dots on the side of one of the bookmarks and dragged to the folder I created in Step 1. Then all of my mobile bookmarks were on my Bookmark Bar.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem starts with Chrome on mobile saving bookmarks (by default) to a separate folder, which is not a regular folder. Like the others, I don't think syncing that folder is possible.

But, if both Chromes are syncing bookmarks (which they do by default), simply create another bookmarks folder (this can be done on mobile or desktop), and move all mobile bookmarks into that new folder. Since it's a folder you created, it'll sync.

For the future, simply save your bookmarks directly into the folder, and not to its default Mobile Bookmarks folder.

Comment: That folder is sync'd by default -- it's just a question of why it disappeared from the UI in the newer versions of Desktop Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

With new version of Google Chrome (66) it's still not possible to do that. You have to use workaround provided by @Frank but things changed a bit.

There is no longer **chrome://bookmarks/#3**. You have to utilize **chrome://bookmarks/?id=3**

- Open up Bookmarks Manager (use one of the methods described above)
- Click on the Mobile bookmarks and notice how the Chrome URL has
  changed
- Now simply drag and drop that URL into Bookmarks Bar. That's
  it.

If you prefer the long version with screenshots you can find one at my blog  [Add Google Chrome mobile bookmarks into Bookmarks Bar](https://evotec.xyz/add-google-chrome-mobile-bookmarks-bookmarks-bar/)

Comment: My list at this url contains only bookmarks of several years old.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find my recent saved pages amoung synced Chrome bookmarks until I realized that they were saved not by [Chrome Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome) but by [Google Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) that has it's own bookmarking functionality. 
Saved web pages list is combined there with favorite places lists.

But while [favorite places](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106399/how-do-i-manage-want-to-go-and-favorite-places-in-google-maps/113627#113627) are synced to Google Maps Web, the saved web pages list has no web interface currently.

It can only be downloaded as csv via [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout) by [image]
 icon.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Bookmarks manager, after that click mobile bookmark, select all with ctrl A and copy
2. Create New folder three dots in bookmarks bar , and then add name
3. then open the new folder  and paste